# Send Google Buisness Messages using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, php-curl, google-business

I am trying to send responses to inbound Google Business Messages via my web app. Unfortunately the Google documentation doesn't include PHP examples, nor can I find any reference to PHP helper libraries for business messaging. I'm more than happy to work with PHP curl but...

This line in Google's cURL example defeats me...

-H "$(oauth2l header --json ./service_account_key.json businessmessages)"

Is there any way to translate this to PHP cURL?

I haven't found a cURL-to-PHP auto-translator that is willing to deal with it either.

I believe it is asking the target server to execute some command, but how do I get PHP to do that?

Comment: You're probably better off using Google's PHP  client package `https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient`

Comment: @delboy1978uk I've been through the PHP client pkg and there's no mention of Google Buisness Messaging. Is it named something else?

Comment: can use the `https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php` library

Comment: @MohammadSalehi Yes, but how does that fix the issue with the actual cURL request above that contains the authentication request? Is there a way to pass this separately acquired authentication in the "send business message" api request?